# How to display the members of a second Class in a Datagridview

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have an ArrayList of objects (for example Employees).

**Employee Class Properties:**

- name (String),
- email (String),
- telephone (String),
- workgroup (Workgroup)

The Employee class has a property Workgroup, which contains a Workgroup-object:

**Workgroup Class Properties:**

- name (String),
- email (String)).

I tried to display all values and set the **DataPropertyName** of the columns to these values:

- "**name**",
- "**email**",
- "**telephone**",
- "**workgroup.name**",
- "**workgroup.email**".

**But this did not work for the workgroup-properties.**

**Is there a simple way without writing a wrapper-Class, that exposes all properties of employee and workgroup?**

I have many objects with similar relationships in my project and want to migrate from datatables with native sql to an object-relational-mapper like nhibenate. So it would be very expensive to write additional mapper-classes for all views. I'm also programming in java with Eclipse and there i can solve this problem using the Interface ITableLabelProvider.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific than "this did not work". Do you get any error messages in the output window of the debugger, for example?

Comment: "this did not work" means, that the specified columns remain empty. This did not raise any error.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. but could you please post it as an answer. Then you can accept it to show that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a solution:**

I add an adapted DataGridViewTextBoxCell:

```
Public Class SpecialDataGridViewTextBoxCell
    Inherits DataGridViewTextBoxCell

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.new()
    End Sub

    'Overriding basic function
    Protected Overrides Function GetFormattedValue( _
            ByVal value As Object, _
            ByVal rowIndex As Integer, _
            ByRef cellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle, _
            ByVal valueTypeConverter As System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, _
            ByVal formattedValueTypeConverter As System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, _
            ByVal context As DataGridViewDataErrorContexts _
        ) As Object
        Dim dataproperty As String = Me.OwningColumn.DataPropertyName
        If Not dataproperty Is Nothing AndAlso dataproperty.IndexOf(".") > 0 Then
            If value Is Nothing Then
                Return getValueByDottedProperty(Me.OwningRow.DataBoundItem, dataproperty)
            Else
                Return getValueByDottedProperty(value, dataproperty)
            End If
        Else
            Return MyBase.GetFormattedValue(value, rowIndex, cellStyle, valueTypeConverter, formattedValueTypeConverter, context)
        End If
    End Function

    Private Function getValueByDottedProperty(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal dataPropertyName As String) As String
        If Not obj Is Nothing AndAlso Not obj Is System.DBNull.Value Then
            If Not dataPropertyName Is Nothing AndAlso dataPropertyName.Length > 0 AndAlso dataPropertyName.IndexOf(".") > 0 Then
                Dim part1 As String = dataPropertyName.Substring(0, dataPropertyName.IndexOf("."))
                Dim part2 As String = dataPropertyName.Substring(dataPropertyName.IndexOf(".") + 1)
                Dim val As Object = getPropertyFromObject(obj, part1)
                If Not val Is Nothing AndAlso Not val Is System.DBNull.Value Then
                    Return getValueByDottedProperty(val, part2)
                Else
                    Return ""
                End If
            Else
                Dim val As Object = getPropertyFromObject(obj, dataPropertyName)
                If Not val Is Nothing AndAlso Not val Is System.DBNull.Value Then
                    Return val.ToString
                Else
                    Return ""
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Return ""
        End If
    End Function

    Private Function getPropertyFromObject(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal propertyName As String) As Object
        Dim pInfo As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = obj.GetType.GetProperty(propertyName)
        If pInfo Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        End If
        Dim val As Object = pInfo.GetValue(obj, Nothing)
        Return val
    End Function

End Class
```

I added a function to generate a DatagridViewTextBoxColumn:

```
Public Shared Function createSpecialDataGridViewTextBoxColumn(ByVal headername As String, ByVal datapropertyname As String) As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Dim specialTextBoxColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    With specialTextBoxColumn
        .DataPropertyName = datapropertyname
        .HeaderText = headername
        .CellTemplate = New SpecialDataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With
    Return specialTextBoxColumn
End Function
```

Then i set the adapted DataGridViewTextBoxCell as CellTemplate to the DatagridVieColumn:

```
With Me.DataGridView1
    .AutoGenerateColumns = False
    .Columns.Clear()
    .Columns.Add(createSpecialDataGridViewTextBoxColumn("Name", "name"))
    .Columns.Add(createSpecialDataGridViewTextBoxColumn("Email", "email"))
    .Columns.Add(createSpecialDataGridViewTextBoxColumn("Telephone", "telephone"))
    .Columns.Add(createSpecialDataGridViewTextBoxColumn("Name (Wrkgrp)", "workgroup.name"))
    .Columns.Add(createSpecialDataGridViewTextBoxColumn("Email (Wrkgrp.)", "workgroup.email"))
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Friend Class Employee
    Public name As String
    Public Phone As String
    Public Email As String
    Private oWorkGroup As workGroup

    Public Property WorkGroupEmail As String
        Get
            Return oWorkGroup.Email
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            oWorkGroup.Email = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property WorkGroupName As String
        Get
            Return oWorkGroup.Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            oWorkGroup.Name = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Will this work for you? Create properties to display the WorkGroup properties

Comment: This would work for this example, but i'm looking for a generic solution. I have in my project about 90 different objects, which are related to another like in the sample above. I prefer a solution with an extented DataGridViewColumn, that can handles this kind of DataProperties.